# Determine if the sets $A=\{(x,y) \mid x <1\}$ and $B=\{(x,y)\mid y=x^2\}$ are closed?

Tags: general-topology

> Determine if the sets $A=\{(x,y) \mid x <1\}$ and $B=\{(x,y)\mid y=x^2\}$ are closed?

For $A$ I have that the complement $A^c=\{(x,y) \mid x \geqslant1\}$ which is closed so this would imply that $A$ is open? For $B$ I'm not entirely sure how to determine this. $B$ seems to be closed, but I'm not sure how to formalize this?

Comment: **Hint :** Write $B$ as the preimage of a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ by a continuous function over $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Note that showing that a set is open does not in general show that it is not closed; it does in the case of proper, non-empty subsets of $\Bbb R^2$, but unless you’ve proved that fact, you can’t use it here. To show that $A$ is not closed, show that $A$ has a limit point that is not in $A$.

Answer (score 1):

The complement of $A$ is not open as any open disk centered on $(1,0)$ has a non empty intersection with $A$. Hence $A$ is not closed.

$B$ is the inverse image of the closed subset $\{0\}$ of $\mathbb R$ under the continuous map $f : (x,y) \mapsto y-x^2$. Hence it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Take the sequence of elements in $ A $  defined by
$$u_n=(1-e^{-n},0).$$

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}u_n=(1,0)\notin A$$
$$\implies A \text{ is not closed}$$